# Tensorflow TF_records Generate Error

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-storage

When I try to generate TF record, I'm getting the following error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 112, in <module>
  tf.app.run()
  File "/home/harisohmnaathss/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site- 
  packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.
   py", line 124, in run
   _sys.exit(main(argv))
   File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 98, in main
   writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
   File "/home/harisohmnaathss/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site- 
   packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/tf_rec
    ord.py", line 106, in __init__
   compat.as_bytes(path), compat.as_bytes(compression_type), status)
   File "/home/harisohmnaathss/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site- 
   packages/tensorflow/python/framework/err
   ors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
   c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
  tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: ; No such file or 
   directory
```

The command that I try to run is:

```
    python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/Train_labels.csv
    --output_path=data/train.records
```

Any ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you following any example? The command that you have to run depends of your generate_tfrecord.py. Can you check if your input file is called Train_labels.csv or train_labels.csv.

Answer (score 0):

You are supplying output path as `data/train.records` instead of `data/train.tfrecord`

Comment: hi I'm still getting error though I replaced "traim.tfrecord"